# Gzip compression in Cassini in Visual Studio 2008/2010

Tags: visual-studio, compression, gzip, cassini

Is is possible to turn on gzip compression in Cassini server under VS 2008/2010?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As far as I know this is not possible - Cassini does not support comprssion.

Try [IIS Express](http://learn.iis.net/page.aspx/868/iis-express-overview/) as an alternative for Cassini, that's why MS released it.

Answer (score 0):

[UWS Pro web server](http://ultidev.com/Forums/yaf_postst633_Welcome-to-UltiDev-Web-Server-Pro.aspx), the replacement of UltiDev Cassini, does have [compression](http://ultidev.com/Forums/yaf_postsm2836_UWS-Screenshots.aspx#post2836), and it can be used for ASP.NET development as well as production hosting.